# Neutralino js : WebView2Loader.dll was not found

Tags: javascript, web, neutralinojs

i was working on a small web application when i decided to ship it as a native exe.
I knew about Electron js but it seemed that the base size is very large and that it's memory hogging.
Then i found about Neutralino js and it looks like it solves those problems.
I went to the getting-started tutorial and followed all the steps but when i tried to run the application it said that "neutralino-win_x64.exe was stopped with error code 3221225781"
After i went to google for some help all i found is that the problem is that the application can't found WebView2Loader.dll
I use windows 11 and webview2 as well as microsoft edge are installed by default.
I don't know what to do and help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, the bin folder is kinda corrupted, download this file and replace it to the bin folder, it'll work

https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs/releases/download/v4.14.0/neutralinojs-v4.14.0.zip

good luck